# How to populate a dropdown using the html helper "options" in a scala template (play 2.0)

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I'm really a starter with Scala, so pardon me if I'm stupid here!

I'm using play2.0/Scala for an assignment.

I want to populate a dropdown with distinct values(timesheetId here) and labels(a concat of 2 date values). So I did this.

```
@select(effortForm("timesheetId"),options(timesheets.map(aTimesheet=> aTimesheet.timesheetId.toString -> (aTimesheet.fromDate + " to " + aTimesheet.toDate))),'_label->"Choose Timesheet (*)")
```

But the page has a dropdown populated with same value (as a tuple) and label for options under select.

Overloaded method value [apply] cannot be applied to (List[(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)])

I want to see this as result

```
<option value="1">Sun Apr 08 18:23:32 PDT 2012 to Sun Apr 08 18:23:32 PDT 2012</option>
```

Please help!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this:

```
@select(
  effortForm("timesheetId"),
  timesheets.map{ t =>
    t.timesheetId.toString -> (t.fromDate + " to " + t.toDate)
  },
  '_label- > "Choose Timesheet (*)"
)
```

Looking at the implementation of [select](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/views/helper/select.scala.html#L13), it looks like the second parameter should be a `Seq[(String, String)]` which would already be the case for your `timesheets.map{ }`.

[`options(...)`](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/views/helper/Helpers.scala#L70) provides conveniences methods to constructs the `Seq[(String, String)]` and there is not a method that applies here.

Answer (score 0):

There is an excellent example in the samples/java installation directory that ships with your play installation. See "forms". SignUp - > Countries